# Batch Change dir and use current dir as command

Tags: batch-file, set, cd

i try to write a CMD to run a script written by me.

Script syntax is:

```
luajit.exe loader.lua nyufxlua "workingpath" suffix
```

workingpath and location of library are different.

I tried following:

```
@echo off

IF "%1%" == "" (
    GOTO :NOFILE
) ELSE (
    GOTO :FILE
)

:NOFILE
ECHO NO FILE GIVEN!
GOTO :EXIT

:FILE
SET "P=%CD%"
PUSHD C:\Projects\FXSpindle\trunk\deps\script\bin
luajit.exe loader.lua nyufxlua "%P%" %1%

:EXIT
```

I switch direcotry, run my file, but paramether "workingdir" is not correct.
workingdir should be the path i runned this scirpt from (script is stored in System32 of my Windows)

As "workingdir" is always C:\Projects\FXSpindle\trunk\deps\script\bin given, but not the path i have opened my command line...

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have the problem solved. I havent realized that i have to use POPD after PUSHD - so i was in wrong directory...

The correct code is:

```
@echo off

IF "%1%" == "" (
    GOTO :NOFILE
) ELSE (
    GOTO :FILE
)

:NOFILE
ECHO NO FILE GIVEN!
GOTO :EXIT

:FILE
SET "P=%CD%"
POPD C:\Projects\FXSpindle\trunk\deps\script\bin
luajit.exe loader.lua nyufxlua "%P%" %1%

:EXIT
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `%1` to access the first parameter, without the trailing %

Comment: Oh, OK. But whaty the difference between %1% and %1 ?

Comment: Command-line arguments aren't variables and the [correct syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) is `%1`...`%9`.